# how to replace distinct with something faster in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, distinct

I have a query like this -

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.y_no) 
FROM xyz c 
WHERE c.xdate>='2013-09-01';
```

Because of DISTINCT, my query taking too much time. This query scanning around 150 million records. I already have index on xdate. Please suggest me something faster.

Thank you.

Comment: Well if you need **distinct** values then you have to use `DISTINCT`. [Slow or not](http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/07/24/the-effects-of-distinct-in-a-sql-query/) (see link). Of course there may be some workaround to avoid it (for example if you can assume something about columns content, relations or other) but we need **much more context** to guess or suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a compound index on xdate, y_nro will help too much

Comment: in what order? xdate,y_no or y_no,xdate?

Comment: in this order:  xdate,y_no